# Safely store code(html/js..) into database

Tags: database, validation, sanitization

So I'm working on a small plugin, and this plugin allows users to save data to my db. This data is mostly plain text but 3 fields are will have tags inside them.

1 field can be used to save all kind of code(js/php/html....) into my db, and 2 fields can only accept JS code.

My question how should I save this kind of data into the DB to prevent injections and such.

*I am still new to the whole validation stuff so any tips and help would be nice (dont put the links to the wordpress docs in the comments below, I already read those)*

*My code until now*

```
  $wpdb->insert($table,
      array(
          'field-no-tags'       => sanitize_text_field($_POST['field-no-tags']),
          'field-have-all-tags' => $_POST['field-have-all-tags'],
          'field-have-js-tags'  => $_POST['field-have-js-tags']
      )
      ,array(
          's%',
          's%',
      )
  );


  <form>

      <label>No code allowed</label>

      <textarea name="field-no-tags"></textarea>


      <label>All code allowed</label>

      <textarea name="field-have-all-tags"></textarea>


      <label>Only JS allowed</label>

      <textarea name="field-have-js-tags"></textarea>

      <button type="submit">Save</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want all values to be text contents, but some fields should allow a limited set of HTML tags (no tags, all tags, `<script>` tags), right? `strip_tags` is obviously insufficient. Are you sure you want to allow PHP code? One of the problems you'll encounter is that nobody uses `CDATA` in script tags, and that's why simple XML processing is not enough to filter `<script>` tags. Allowing code in text is quite unusual, why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: This plugin is the wordpress version of a Javascript plugin, one that has callback functions(hooks), which allows a user to add his/her own javascript. The other field is a field where some HTML is used to build parts for the javascript plugin(this part is very flexible and therfor it cant be build by the plugin it self).

Comment: Don't you think it could be sufficient to have one field which allows arbitrary HTML code and one which accepts arbitrary JS code? Everybody who can set JS code to execute on a page has full control over the page, so it might be unnecessary to try to control the HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

there are two possible injection vectors, server side and client side

- server side - Just don't write your own SQL and use the more high level DB access APIs, in your case probably `update_option`. If you must to access the DB at lower level make sure the API use [wpdb::prepare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) while generating the SQL, which is true for `insert` but not true for `query`  which requires the use of `prepare` if you use placeholders in the query.
- client side - You should never let anyone that is not the admin of the site to admin the plugin. This means it is not suitable to use in a network unless you will restrict the access there to only the super admin. Any other configuration will enable the site's users to do XSS attacks against other users of the site.

Comment: All of the data is stored in a custom database table, so I cant use the update_option function for this. I do have build in a user manager, which allows the admin to select the users which can use the form.

Comment: answer editted.